# Generate various outputs jasper in an unique report

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

Is it possible to get various outputs of Jasper (like three jasper outputs) and make a unique export report? In the order words, unify the results in an unique file exported.

Comment: What do you mean `various outputs`? Do you need dynamic report? Or do you want to vary the view of exported file (different design for each format, for example, pdf file should be different from a file in xls format)?

Comment: Yes, I need dynamic report! How can I do it ?

Comment: You can achieve this with help of [JasperReports API](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/index.html) or [DynamicJasper API](http://dynamicjasper.com/documentation-examples/api-docs/). You can find samples in `%jasperreports_folder%\demo\samples` folder from JasperReports distribution package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question well, you can merge multiple JasperPrints into a single export this way:

```
List <JasperPrint> jasperPrints = new ArrayList <JasperPrint>();
jasperPrints.add(jasperPrint1);
.
.
jasperPrints.add(jasperPrintn);

JRPdfExporter exp = new JRPdfExporter();
exp.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT_LIST, jasperPrints);
exp.exportReport();
```